# Symfony2 commit form using Doctrine - MappingException

Tags: php, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm, propel

I have created a form using Propel which submits fine, and validates. The problem comes when I try to commit the $user object - I get a MappingException. I really have no idea where this is coming from as previous references to $user seem to be fine.

Note that the commented line is taken from some of the form guides, but inserts an empty row into the database (though a var_dump of $user shows it has all of the information. I would be happy if I could get that to work as an alternative.

Here's my code:

```
namespace LifeMirror\APIBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use LifeMirror\APIBundle\Model\Users;
use LifeMirror\APIBundle\Model\UsersQuery;
use LifeMirror\APIBundle\Form\Type\UsersType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->processForm(new Users());
    }

    private function processForm(Users $user)
    {
        $statusCode = $user->isNew() ? 201 : 204;
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $form = $this->createForm(new UsersType(), $user);
        //die(phpinfo());
        $form->bind(array(
            "firstName" => $this->getRequest()->request->get('firstName'),
            "lastName" => $this->getRequest()->request->get('lastName'),
            "email" => $this->getRequest()->request->get('email'),
            "password" => $this->getRequest()->request->get('password'),
            "dob" => array(
                "year" => json_decode($this->getRequest()->request->get('dob'))->year,
                "month" => json_decode($this->getRequest()->request->get('dob'))->month,
                "day" => json_decode($this->getRequest()->request->get('dob'))->day
            ),
            "location" => $this->getRequest()->request->get('location'),
            "tutorialWatched" => $this->getRequest()->request->get('tutorialWatched'),
            "challengeEmails" => $this->getRequest()->request->get('challengeEmails'),
            "mailingList" => $this->getRequest()->request->get('mailingList')
        ));

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            //$user->save();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

            $response = new Response();
            $response->setStatusCode($statusCode);
            return $response;
        }
        $view = View::create($form, 400);
        $view->setFormat('json');
        return $view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you try to persist a Propel object using doctrine.

That's surely not what you want, even if it's theorically possible, if you add some doctrine mapping for the `Model\Users` class.

What you surely want is to persist the `$user`'s state:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $user->save(); // propel object implements Active Record pattern, they can save themselves, no doctrine entityManager needed.
}
```

Comment: I have tried that but it creates an empty row in the database. I enabled MySQL query logging and noticed that it the query it runs is `INSERT INTO `users` (`ID`) VALUES (NULL)`.

Comment: By the way, this is more a Propel problem. You should check the state of your `$user` object before trying to save it. It's surely an empty  object. Furthermore, your propel mapping is maybe wrong. You maybe forgot to describe the id as an auto increment primary key.

Comment: what is your propel mapping for this object?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but which file do you mean?

Comment: You are using Propel, right ? If so, you should have a mapping configuration file (xml).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you're field names are `firstName`, `lastName` and so on? Typically Propel generates field names in capitalized CamelCase, thus I would expect to see `FirstName` and `LastName`. If the field names don't match exactly then Propel will not assign the values, and thus result in an empty `INSERT`. You can dump a list of the `User` field names like so:

```
var_dump(BaseUserPeer::getFieldNames());
```

Comment: Well, for debugging you could just put it where you currently have the `die(phpinfo());`, then do a simple `exit;`. Again, this is just to see what the Model's field names actually are, they will need to match your form input `name` attributes or your binding names... or both.

Comment: ` Fatal error: Class 'LifeMirror\APIBundle\Controller\BaseUsersPeer' not found in /home/nginx/domains/lifemirror.org/public/src/LifeMirror/APIBundle/Controller/RegisterController.php on line 24` (it's Users, not User)

Comment: That's odd. Well, you may need to find where that Peer class is, if you generated from Propel 1.6 it has to be there somewhere. Or are you using an older version of Propel?

Comment: Yes, 1.6.7. BaseUsersPeer.php is in LifeMirror\APIBundle\Model\om, which is included in UsersPeer.php, which I've just included in RegisterController with no effect.

Comment: Hmmm... if you included the file and PHP says the class doesn't exist, I'm not sure what else you can do. I suppose you could do an explicit `require('/path/to/BaseUsersPeer.php');` before doing the `var_dump(BaseUserPeer::getFieldNames());` call.

Comment: Still showing the same error. Could something  be missing from BaseUsersPeer?

Comment: That's unlikely if you generated the classes. You could always re-generate, and maybe double check the class name as defined in the file - they can be changed in the build.properties.